# MailChimp API 3.0 search-members query format

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I’m trying to use the [MailChimp - Search Members](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/search-members/) function. I want to use this action as a general search for retrieving members from all lists which match a query.

When I try the URI as formatted in the example:

```
https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?query=freddie@
```

I get the following error:

```
{"type":"https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"An error occurred: Sorry, we're unable to search at the moment.","instance":""}
```

If I leave out the query parameter I receive the following error:

```
{"type":"https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"Please provide 'query' parameter in the query string to search","instance":""}
```

So the method is available and my request URI is being parsed.

I conclude that the query parameter is incorrectly formed, however after extensive research I cannot find out how to format the query parameter.

Comment: What tool are you using to make your request? Also, how are you providing your api key in your request?

Comment: *apparently pertinent information is not allowed in this forum* New users aren't allowed to post multiple links to cut down on spam and malicious links in posts. It was picking up the links in your code as attempts to link to pages because your code wasn't formatted as code. Also note that [this restriction gets lifted once you reach 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an issue at Mail Chimp.
If you get it make a GET call to your root url e.g. 
https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/
And send them your account Id along with the issue.
They can then reindex your lists.
Thanks anyone who invested time in this issue

## See reply below.

J (MailChimp) 
Jul 24, 5:49 PM EDT 
Hey Dev, thanks so much for providing that info. I found the account and was able to replicate the error you are seeing - looks like it's account specific.

I reindexed your lists and then was able to make the same call successfully this time. If you do ever run across this issue again, that is likely what is going on. Shooting us an email or jumping in chats with this request will get it resolved in no time :)

Let me know if you are still experiencing that same error when making this call and I'll be happy to take another look, but you should be good to go at this point. Hope all is well, and have a great rest of your week!

============================================